# Como converter uma CheckBox em um Toggle Button?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview, button

Pessoal eu criei uma coluna de checkbox - *DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn* - no *DataGridView* e gostaria de saber se é possível, e como faço para esta coluna se tornar uma coluna de botão de habilitar ou desabilitar, um *Toggle Button*?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando a biblioteca .NET Framework, veja no código abaixo, que irá converter todas `CheckBox` da coluna para um *ToggleButton*:

Em Visual Basic:

```
For Each column As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in SuaDataGrid.Columns
     For Each item In column.Cells
           CType(item, DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button
     Next
Next
```

Em C#:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column in SuaDataGrid.Columns)
{
     foreach (var i in column.Cells) {
          ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) i).Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
     }
}
```

Fontes:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793105/toggle-button-control) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681046/programatically-loop-through-a-datagridview-and-check-checkboxes)